# supervisor.con on centos 6

Tags: configuration, centos6, supervisord

I installed supervisor using easy_install, however, the conf file seems to be missing, and I really wanted to have a base to start my configuration.

Does anyone know where can I find this file or an example at least?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found out, just had to run echo_supervisord_conf > supervisor.conf

Here is the ref: http://supervisord.org/installing.html#creating-a-configuration-file